# Updating value in Dictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have set up my own class called myObjectClass as follows:

```
@interface myObjectClass : NSObject{
    NSMutableString *theRef;
    NSMutableString *theLat;
    NSMutableString *theLong;
    NSMutableString *theDesc;
    NSMutableString *theTime;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *theRef;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *theLat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *theLong;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *theDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *theTime;


@end
```

When I add a new entry to my dictionary, everything works OK.  When I try to edit an existing entry, it crashes.

```
myObjectClass *myRouteData = [[myObjectClass alloc]init];
[myRouteData.theRef setString:myKey.text];
[myRouteData.theLat setString:tf1.text];
[myRouteData.theLong setString:tf2.text];
[myRouteData.theDesc setString:myDesc.text];
[myRouteData.theTime setString:myTime.text];

//The values for all of the above are the correct updated values.
//crashes on next line for existing object


[[masterDelegate myData] setObject:myRouteData forKey:myKey.text];

[myRouteData release];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the error message when it crashes.

Comment: Why NSMutableString members instead of NSString?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x2a417a00)

Comment: I used NSMutableString as I want to be able to change the contents.  I changed it to NSString - same behaviour/crash.

Comment: All I can think is that it is an issue with memory allocation.  I will try to update a tem dict and then copy to the normal dict.  Good idea?